# Jupyter notebook: How to save a copy of a notebook to a different directory

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

Is it possible to save a copy of a Jupyter notebook in a different directory?

My scenario is as such: I have jupyterhub set up using the docker spawner to create jupyter containers for users. I want all of these users to have access to a shared notebook, which contains a template for certain types of work. This notebook is served via a read-only volume mount into a `/shared` directory under `/work`. Users should then be able to modify and save a copy into the parent directory, to which they have access. However, the 'make a copy' function seems to only want to make a copy in the same directory, which is of course read only. Is there a way to change this functionality?

Alternate solutions also welcome!

(For reference, this is using the `r-notebook` kernel, but I doubt that makes a difference)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [nbexamples](https://libraries.io/github/danielballan/nbexamples) extension

It accomplishes the same task.

You can specify the reviewed directory of nbexamples as your shared read-only directory.

Users will be able to fetch a copy and the copy will get stored inside home directory of user.

Comment: FTR: `nbexamples` basically makes usage of the default python function `shutil.copyfile(src, dest)`